# ruby hash iteration without `each`

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby hash `a` as follows:

```
a = {
      "module" => 'students',
      "data" => [
        {
          "age" => 12,
          "uid" => 'sd3wrew'
        },
        {
          "age" => 10,
          "uid" => '43e43r'
        },
        {
          "age" => 10,
          "uid" => 'ft34f'
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to collect all `uid` from above hash and get an array like:

```
b = ['sd3wrew', '43e43r', 'ft34f']
```

so, I have code to do this, which loop through it.

```
b = []
a['data'].each do |e|
  b << e['uid']
end
```

Is there anyway to achieve this result without looping `each` and much concise?

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for the functional programming concept called ["map."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29)

```
b = a['data'].collect {|e| e['uid'] }
# or
b = a['data'].map {|e| e['uid'] }
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map

Comment: Have a look through the [Enumerable](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable) library, there's lots of good things in there.

Answer (score -2):

This will print each key in a hash if key is equal with `uid`:

```
b = a["data"].each_key { |e| print e if e='uid' }
```

Comment: Isn't this still using iteration? I thought the poster was asking for without it...

Comment: The question stated to be much concise. I thick this is much concise!

Comment: I didn't vote down but the person who did probably did because although you made it more concise, you still used each.

Comment: I would assume the downvotes are because this code does not do what the OP wants. In fact, it just errors (``NoMethodError: undefined method `each_key' for #<Array:0x007fdbd419c870>``). And uses `=` instead of `==`.